# Plist Not able to write data

Tags: ios, swift

Below i mention my code. i have array of dictionary. this dictionary consists number of dictionaries which is  type dictionaries.
When I try to write This Array to plist, plist show blank.

please help me.

```
var profileDATA:Dictionary! = [String:Any]()
var educationDATA = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()
var portfolioDATA:Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>? = Array()
var achievementDATA :Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>? = Array()
var skillDATA = Array<Any>()
var experianceDATA:Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>? = Array()
var templeteType: String!

func DataStoreForEachPDF(_ FileName:String)
{
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let folderpathforNormal: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.docDire).appendingPathComponent("Profile").path
    let userpath:String = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderpathforNormal).appendingPathComponent("UserData").path
    if !filemgr.fileExists(atPath: userpath)
    {
        try? filemgr.createDirectory(atPath: userpath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    }

    let filepath:String = URL(fileURLWithPath: userpath).appendingPathComponent("user.plist").path
    var DataArray = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()
    let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filepath)
    if array != nil
    {
        DataArray = array as! Array
    }
    var UserDataDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()
    var str = ""
    let userdefault:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if userdefault.bool(forKey: "fresher")
    {
        str = userdefault.string(forKey: "fresherdisc")!
        UserDataDictionary.updateValue(str , forKey: "experiancedata")
    }
    else
    {UserDataDictionary.updateValue(experianceDATA as Any, forKey: "experiancedata")}
    UserDataDictionary.updateValue(profileDATA, forKey: "profiledata")
    UserDataDictionary.updateValue(educationDATA, forKey: "educationdata")
    UserDataDictionary.updateValue(skillDATA, forKey: "skilldata")
    UserDataDictionary.updateValue(achievementDATA as Any, forKey: "achievementdata")
    UserDataDictionary.updateValue(portfolioDATA as Any, forKey: "portfoliodata")
    UserDataDictionary.updateValue(templeteType, forKey: "templetetype")
    var userDataMainDict = Dictionary<String ,Dictionary<String,Any>>()
    userDataMainDict.updateValue(userDataMainDict, forKey: FileName)
    if DataArray.count == 0
    {
        DataArray = [userDataMainDict]
    }
    else{DataArray.append(userDataMainDict)}
    print(DataArray)
    (DataArray as NSArray).write(toFile: filepath, atomically: true)
}
```

Please Update if any error in my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736244/swift-3-cannot-write-data-to-plist-file

Comment: I already Store plist file at document directory. Problem is that data not store in it.

Comment: @RakeshPatel can u tell me why your using plist for writing data ?

Comment: Plist use to store a user profile data.